# SalesForce SOQL highest number from size column

Tags: soql, lookup

i'm new to SOQL and SF, so bear with me :) I have Sales_Manager__c object tied to Rent__c via Master-Detail relationship. What i need is to get Manager with highest number of Rent deals for a current year. I figured out that the Rents__r.size column stores that info. The question is how can i gain access to the size column and retrieve highest number out of it? [image: Here is the picture of query i have]
My SOQL code

```
SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Rents__r WHERE StartDate__c=THIS_YEAR) FROM Sales_Manager__c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size` here is not a column in the sense of a field that you can access and filter on directly in SOQL. It appears in your screenshot a property of a list that's being shown to you by whatever query tool you're using. Additionally, when you query data in Apex, it is a method (`List.size()`) that you can call on the property that represents the child objects you queried (which here would be called `Rents__r`).

However, unless your data volume is very small, performing a parent-child query like this one and then iterating over it in Apex to find the greatest value of `Rents__r.size()` is very inefficient and likely to run into limits issues.

There's a way you can find Manager with the highest count of Rent child records directly in SOQL, with no iteration required: perform an aggregate query on the child object, using a `GROUP BY` and `LIMIT` clause to pull out the parent object with the greatest child count. Since aggregate queries just got "cheaper" in Summer '18, it's also limits-efficient.

It'd look something like this:

```
SELECT Sales_Manager__c, count(Id) 
FROM Rents__c
WHERE StartDate__c = THIS_YEAR
GROUP BY Sales_Manager__c
ORDER BY count(Id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That'll yield the single Manager record Id with the highest count of rents, and the count of Rent objects (`count(Id)` is a way of expressing the count of records in a SOQL aggregate query). Note that you'll need to replace `Sales_Manager__c` in the `SELECT` clause with the name of the lookup field on the `Rent__c` object.

See [SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm) and surrounding documentation for more information on using aggregate functions and queries.

If you're using this in Apex, note that the return value of an aggregate query is a `List<AggregateResult>`, rather than a `List<someSobjectOrOther>`. You can use `myAggregateResult.get('expr0')` to get the value of the first selected field (and increase the index for each successive field), or you can use aliasing to assign an explicit name:

```
List<AggregateResult> ars = [SELECT Sales_Manager__c manager, count(Id) count ...];
for (AggregateResult ar : ars) {
    System.debug(ar.get('manager'));
}
```

Comment: Wait, I thought that you could call `.size()` on an embedded child object list. I know that it'll give you issues if you end up querying too many child records, but it is possible since the in-memory representation is literally a `List<Sobject>`, no?

Comment: You certainly can, Derek - sorry if I did not make that clear. But it's not an efficient way to find the parent record with the greatest child count.

Comment: @DerekF I hope my edit makes that issue clearer.

Comment: Thanks David for great explanation and example, it totally work for me.